# How to setup permissions for simpleUser and anonymous in CruiseControl.NET security

Tags: security, cruisecontrol.net

I want anonymous user can view projects' status and logs but can not start/stop/force them, while regular user can do everything to projects. But I don't know whether cc.net supports setting permissions to anonymous users.

So I looked up documents and wrote following configuration, to make sure "simpleuser" can view only :

```
<internalSecurity>
  <users>
    <passwordUser name="a" password="1"/>
    <simpleUser name="*" />
  </users>
  <permissions>
    <rolePermission name="all" defaultRight="Allow">
      <users>
        <userName name="a"/>
      </users>
    </rolePermission>
    <rolePermission name="ViewOnly" defaultRight="Deny" viewConfiguration="Allow" viewProject="Allow" viewSecurity="Allow">
      <users>
        <userName name="*"/>
      </users>
    </rolePermission>
  </permissions>
</internalSecurity>


<project name="SQLBackup">
  <security type="defaultProjectSecurity">
    <permissions>
      <rolePermission name="all" ref="all" />
      <rolePermission name="ViewOnly" ref="ViewOnly" />
    </permissions>
  </security>
</project>
```

But cc.net 1.6 told me I don't have 'view' permission when I log as 'simpleuser'.

What's wrong?

And anyone knows how to setup permission to anonymous user for cc.net server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the "defaults" tag. :

```
<internalSecurity> 
    <users>
        <simpleUser name="*"/>
        ...
    </users>

    <defaults viewProject="Allow" defaultRight="Deny"/>

    <permissions>
    ...
    </permissions>

</internalSecurity>
```